# Where the images get stored in Azure Kubernetes Cluster after pulling from Azure Container Registry?

Tags: image, azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am using Kubernetes to deploy all my microservices provided by Azure Kubernetes Services.

Whenever I release an update of my microservice which is getting frequently from last one month, it pulls the new image from the Azure Container Registry.

I was trying to figure out where do these images reside in the cluster?

Just like Docker stores, the pulled images in /var/lib/docker & since the Kubernetes uses Docker under the hood may be it stores the images somewhere too.

But if this is the case, how can I delete the old images from the cluster that are not in use anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in guessing that it's mostly up to Docker, or rather to whatever the active CRI plugin is. The Kubelet automatically cleans up old images when disk space runs low so it's rare that you need to ever touch it directly, but if you did (and are using Docker as your runtime) then it would be the same `docker image` commands as per normal.

Answer (score 2):

Clusters with Linux node pools created on Kubernetes v1.19 or greater default to containerd for its container runtime ([Container runtime configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-configuration#container-runtime-configuration)).

To manually remove unused images on a node running containerd:

Identity node names:

```sh
kubectl get nodes
```

Start an interactive debugging container on a node ([Connect with SSH to Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh)):

```sh
kubectl debug node/aks-agentpool-11045208-vmss000003 -it --image=mcr.microsoft.com/aks/fundamental/base-ubuntu:v0.0.11
```

Setup `crictl` on the debugging container ([check for newer releases of crictl](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/releases)):

> The host node's filesystem is available at `/host`, so configure `crictl` to use the host node's `containerd.sock`.

```sh
curl -sL https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/releases/download/v1.23.0/crictl-v1.23.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xzf - -C /usr/local/bin \
    && export CONTAINER_RUNTIME_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/run/containerd/containerd.sock IMAGE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Remove unused images on the node:

```sh
crictl rmi --prune
```

Comment: Can't speak for other cloud vendors, but at least Azure's AKS nodes have `crictl` installed as default under `/host/usr/local/bin`. No need to install on the debuggin pod

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to figure out where do these images reside in the
>   cluster?

With the test and check, the result shows each node in the AKS cluster installed the Docker server, and the images stored like Docker as you say that the image layers stored in the directory /var/lib/docker/.

> how can I delete the old images from the cluster that are not in use
>   anymore?

You can do this through the Docker command inside the node. Follow the steps in [Connect with SSH to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh) to make a connection to the node, then you could delete the image through the Docker CLI `docker rmi image_name:tag`, but carefully with it, make sure the image is really no more useful.

Comment: Yeah, that manually doing process would work may be but I just came to know that Kubernete itself handles deleting the unused images with some time interval. Thanks for the above answer though.